# GPG-Fehler bei owncloud repo: NO_PUBKEY

Tags: 16.04, software-sources, gnupg, owncloud-client

I got following error after updating the sources.list, including the owncloud repo:

```
W: GPG-Fehler: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_16.04  Release: Die folgenden Signaturen konnten nicht überprüft werden, weil ihr öffentlicher Schlüssel nicht verfügbar ist: NO_PUBKEY 4ABE1AC7557BEFF9
W: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_16.04  Release' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Does anyone have had experiences with that issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the repo-key...
Read [the OC download page](https://software.opensuse.org/download/package?project=isv:ownCloud:desktop&package=owncloud-client) again and you'll find:

You can add the repository key to apt. Keep in mind that the owner of the key may distribute updates, packages and repositories that your system will trust (more information). To add the key, run:

```
wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:ownCloud:desktop/Ubuntu_16.04/Release.key
sudo apt-key add - < Release.key
sudo apt-get update
```